# using unix time utility to find thetha equivalence class for quicksort

Tags: unix, time, command

I used the time utility to calculate the user time for a quicksort algorithm with inputs of 10000,20000, ...,60000 words and here are the results I have

```
n( in thousands)   T(n)
1                  1.740
2                  3.7 
3                  5.83  
4                  7.93
5                  10.18  
6                  12.41
```

What I want to find out is f(n) such that T(n)= theta(f(n)) i.e., I need to guess f(n) such that T(n)/f(n) approaches a non-zero constant.
I tried the following f(n) functions but nothing seems to generate the constant

```
f(n) =n
f(n) = nlogn
f(n) = n+sqrt(n)
f(n) = n^2
f(n)=n + logn
f(n)=1/n
```

From what I inferred, T(n) has n as lower bound and n log n as upper bound. So I need a function between these two values. Please help.

Comment: What are you using for input? If it's random, did you repeat your sampling several times and average? Did your timing include the input generation? You might also want to use a wider range of input sizes - you haven't even covered a whole order of magnitude. And of course, how are you trying those functions? Curve-fitting, probably? Did you try adding lower-order terms, since those do exist in the real world, and can be more significant at smaller sizes?

Comment: The inputs are different text files containing 10000/20000/30000.../60000 strings/words. The sampling of the different times yielded almost the same value with marginal difference. I'm assuming the timing included input generation. Here are the commands I used for the same: gcc -0 sort1 sort1.c quicksort.c  \n  time ./sort1 <ins.10000> /dev/null. I have to make do with the files I have been given,hence the limited range. I plotted the points T(n)/f(n) for the different values of f(n) vs. n. Is there a formula that heps us calculate f(n)?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of possible options there. I would start by fitting your data to each of the six equations and seeing what how well the fits work. For instance, if you tried plotting your results you would immediately see that they are in a nearly straight line. Using any graphing software would help you see this. In science and mathematics, this is always a good  idea: **plot your results!**

I was lazy, so I used Excel to fit a straight line to your data and I found the equation:

```
T(n) = 2.1379n - 0.524
```

with an R<sup>2</sup> of 0.9995. Even Excel will give you these R<sup>2</sup> values, to tell you how good the fit is to the data (you want R<sup>2</sup> as close to 1 as possible). Now, this result is quite good, and you could stop there, but I thought I would try to fit your data to the rest of the equations and see what I got. I found that the best fit to your six functions was:

```
T(n) = 0.0327n<sup>2</sup> + 1.911n + 0.219
```

with an R<sup>2</sup> of better than 0.999! Now THAT is a really good fit. Of course, if you want more accuracy, you should probably try this in Igor (which is free) instead of Excel. Especially since Excel has been known to give negative R<sup>2</sup> values.

The take home message, I think is that you should always try plotting your results.  It's so easy these days.  After that, I think you were too concerned about re-inventing the wheel and deriving these fits yourself. There is plenty of software to do this for you.